# OData V4: Is not seeing protected constructor in the class

Tags: c#, json, odata, deserialization

After long research and no solution, I decided to post a question here.
What I'm doing is implementing OData to read, write, update and delete entities.
So, now I'm able to read, create and delete entities with Odata, but I have requirement that, there should not be any public constructors with no argument (it is protected now). Well, whenever I change the public constructor to protected, I'm getting an error(in ModelState) on creating new entity: {"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."} in `Post` ODataController method
I'm wondering if there is some setting that I can set, so it will use protected constructor also, like Newtonsoft JsonConverter does:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
var ODataResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OData<T>>(entitiesJson, settings);
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Product
{
    protected Product() { }
    public Product(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
     public class ODataConfiguration
            {
                public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
                {
                    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
                    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
                    builder.EntityType<Product>();
                    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product").EntityType.Name = "Product";
                    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataApi", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
                    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
                }
            }
```

Controller's Post method:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Product entity)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

entity field in Post methods argument is coming null and I'm checking ModelState and seeing error mentioned above.

The **question** is, I want that OData deserializer sees protected constructor or maybe replace the default OData deserializer with Newtonsoft.Json deserializer.

**UPDATE:**
After some research I found way to set ConstructorHandling, but didn't help:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
```

Any ideas or direction that I can research on?
Thank you.

Comment: `I want that OData deserializer sees protected constructor` Why not just make it `public` then?